# jQuery accordion menu, CSS HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what im trying to achieve is the following.

I have an accordion menu. Now I want to Build an accordion Menu(I call this now Top) inside an accordion Menu(I call this now Bottom).

Im doing this, to present loads of data from a database in a clean way.
Now im trying to adapt the accordion menu that I already got on this.

The data of both, top and bottom, are presented in tables. So first i builded tables inside tables.

If the users clicks on the first Element of each row, the “bottom” menu with the table should slide down.

**HTML**

```
<!-- 2016 -->
  <div id="sh_details">
     <div class="sh_wasserzeichen"></div>
     <article>
       <dl id="sh_accordion">
         <dt id="sh_2016">Headline1</dt>
      <dd><table>

          <tr>
           <th>Überschrift1</th>
           <th>Überschrift2</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td class="inhalt">Inhalt1</td>
           <td>Inhalt2</td>
          </tr>

           <!-- Untertabelle1_1 -->
          <td>
           <table class="table2">


                 <tr>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift1</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift2</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt1</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt2</td>
                 </tr>


             </table>
            </td>

          <tr>
            <td class="inhalt">Inhalt3</td>
            <td>Inhalt4</td>
          </tr>

         <!-- Untertabelle1_2 -->  
        <td> 
         <table class="table2">  



                 <tr>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift3</th>
                  <th>Sub_Überschrift4</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt3</td>
                  <td>Sub_Inhalt4</td>
                 </tr>


         </table>
        </td>

       </table></dd>

         <dt id="sh_january">Headline2</dt>
         <dd>125153226262</dd>
       </dl>
     </article>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/***************************************
************ Details *****************/

#sh_details {background-color:#fff;position: relative; top:0;left:0;width:100%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden;display:none;flex-direction: column;}
.table2 {display:none;}
/***************************************
************ Accordion *****************/
.sh_active {background-color:#ff6600; color:white;padding:0.7%; font-size:13px;}
article  {position:absolute;color: black;width: 90%; height: auto;margin: 0 auto 0 auto;padding-top:75px;padding-left:75px;}
dt, dd {padding:0.5%;width: 50%; height:auto;float: left; margin:0;border-top:1px solid #222;}
dt {font-weight:bold;text-transform: uppercase; background-color:black; color:#ff6600; cursor:pointer;}
dt:first-child {border:none;}
dt:hover {background-color:#ff6600; color:white;padding:0.7%; font-size:13px;}
dd {background-color:#444; line-height:25px; word-spacing:3px;color:#999; display:none;}
```

**jQuery (only the accordion stuff) **

```
 /*SUBTABLE*/   <<<---- not working

   $(document).on('click', 'td', function (event) {
      if($(this).hasClass('inhalt')) {
         $(this).next('.table2').removeClass('table2');}
         event.stopPropagation();
   });

$('#sh_accordion dt').stop().click(function(){  

      <--- Working

      if($(this).hasClass('sh_active')) {
         $(this).removeClass('sh_active');
         $(this).next().slideUp(300);
      } else {
         $(this).parent().children().removeClass('sh_active');
         $(this).addClass('sh_active');
            if($(this).next().is('dd')) {
               $(this).parent().children('dd').slideUp(300);
               $(this).next().slideDown(300);
            }
      }

      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u4y2o270/1/ (dont know why the code is not working, i disabled the display:none's beacause of this)

So every "Sub..." Menu should be hidden by default. If i click on "Inhalt1", the first "bottom" menu should appear and so on.

Hide and Show the top Menu works fine (Headline1, Headline2), but not the bottom menu (table inside table)

**Example: Default is this:**

Headline1

Überschrift1    Überschrift2

Inhalt1     Inhalt2

Inhalt3     Inhalt4

**User clicks "Inhalt1":**

Headline1

Überschrift1    Überschrift2

Inhalt1     Inhalt2

Sub_Überschrift1    Sub_Überschrift2

Sub_Inhalt1     Sub_Inhalt2

Inhalt3     Inhalt4

**//EDIT:**

Start:

Everything is hidden, besides the Headlines (Headline1, Headline2) (this is already working, but not in the fiddle)+

It looks like this:

```
Headline1

Headline2
```

User is clicking on **Headline1**,

The user can only see the following:

```
Headline1

Überschrift1    Überschrift2

Inhalt1         Inhalt2

Inhalt3         Inhalt4

Headline2
```

The user is now clicking on **"Inhalt1"**

The user now sees this the following:

```
Headline1

Überschrift1    Überschrift2

Inhalt1         Inhalt2

Sub_Überschrift1    Sub_Überschrift2

Sub_Inhalt1_1       Inhalt2_2

Inhalt3         Inhalt4

Headline2
```

**//EDIT2:**

Updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u4y2o270/7/

This is what is working so far.

If the user is now under **Headline1** clicking **Inhalt1** the table under it should slideDown // should be showed, the table has the class **.table2** which is by default on **display:none** to be hidden. My idea was, to find the next Item with class **table2** and **remove the class or slide it down**. But its not working.

Same obv. for **Inhalt3**

Comment: **[Here is your working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/u4y2o270/2/)**.. Your problem is still not understandable.. Could you please go step by step on what should happen?

Comment: Sorry, please look at "//EDIT:" on my question. Hope its now better understandable

Comment: In my previous comment, I've added working code for your accordion. Could you please edit it to show how it will be initial stage and then provide the updated link?

Comment: Updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u4y2o270/4/

This is what is working so far.

If the user is now under **Headline1** clicking **Inhalt1** the table under it should slideDown // should be showed, the table has the class **.table2** which is by default on **display:none** to be hidden.

My idea was, to find the next Item with class table2 and remove the class or slide it down. But its not working.

Comment: //EDIT: 
Obvs. Same for **Inhalt3**, if the user is clicking this, the table under **Inhalt3** should be showed.

Comment: **[Like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/u4y2o270/8/)**

Comment: exactly! Im tryingI now to understand this, Thanks you!

Comment: Note.. That will work, only if you have same `html` structure..

Comment: Works! But any idea why the slide-effect is not working and **"Überschrift1"** is jumping to the right-side?

Comment: No idea buddy.. I tried different variations like **[this one](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/u4y2o270/10/)** but couldnt identify the problem..